# What is the Variable Editor in Octave GUI

Tags: matlab, octave

Can someone tell me what the variable editor section of Octave GUI does? Is it supposed to be like MATLAB's Live scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please see screenshots in this below report

http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?53838#comment3